# How to implement multiselect lists and dropdown lists in Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

How should dropdown items (and multiselect) items be managed within Sitecore Commerce and Sitecore?

In our current solution, we have single-line text fields which reference lookup items by name, then we search for the lookup items to pull the relevant properties. This solution won't work well for a multi-language scenario, so I'm wondering how best to provide localization support. Would we create dropdown items within commerce and have those brought into Sitecore, or should those dropdown items stay in Sitecore only, in which case how should we link the dropdown items in Sitecore to the fields on the commerce items?

Comment: Hi Matthew, Sitecore commerce OOTB provides language support. Go to /sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/CommerceEngineDefaultStorefront/Language Configuration, you can see it has a droplink field, by going to that field you can select languages.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal that seems to be more related to the global language settings. I'm asking about having sellable items with dropdown or multiselect list fields and how to manage those between Commerce and Sitecore.

Comment: Hi @MatthewDresser can you add more details to your original question?